# Same sparql query not working for different class

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena

I have created this ontology for Sensor Service provider, which is a module of a indoor sensor web system.  My problem is that when I run a query on my ontology it gives me answer for some classes and for others it returns nothing and gives no error. e.g for getting individuals of a class the "Device" "SensorServiceProvider" and "Information class" returns nothing whereas for other casses it returns the individuals. i removed some of the links from the code .

Here is the ontology data:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
    <!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
    <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
    <!ENTITY p0     
    "http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#">]>

    <rdf:RDF   
    xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#"
     xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:p0="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <owl:Ontology   
    rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation">
        <owl:imports 

   rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation"/>
    </owl:Ontology>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Object Properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#ConnectsTo    
    -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&p0;ConnectsTo">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;TransitiveProperty"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#Implement 
    -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&p0;Implement">
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled- 
           ontology-41#Sensing"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-
          ontology-41#Sensor"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#Store -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&p0;Store">
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&p0;Information"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-  
          ontology-41#SensorServiceProvider"/>
     </owl:ObjectProperty>



    <!--      
     http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#hasInformation     
      -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&p0;hasInformation"/>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#initiates 
        -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&p0;initiates">
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&p0;Management"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&p0;SensorSupportToolbox"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#manage -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&p0;manage">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-
            ontology-41#ContentService"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-
              ontology-41#Middleware_Information"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-
              ontology-41#Sensor_Information"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#provide -- 
      >

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&p0;provide">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-
            ontology-41#SensorServiceProvider"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-
            ontology-41#Services"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Data properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- 
     http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#MiddlewareCode 
     -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&p0;MiddlewareCode">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-
         ontology-41#Middleware_Information"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;integer"/>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>



    <!--  
       http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#MiddlewareID  
       -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&p0;MiddlewareID">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-
          ontology-41#Middleware_Information"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;integer"/>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>



    <!-- 
    http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#MiddlewareRight 
     -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&p0;MiddlewareRight">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled- 
        ontology-41#Middleware_Information"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;boolean"/>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#NodeCode -
    ->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&p0;NodeCode">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-
       ontology-41#Sensor_Information"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;integer"/>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>



    <!-- 
    http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#NodeExplain -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&p0;NodeExplain">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-
          ontology-41#Sensor_Information"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string"/>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#NodeId -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&p0;NodeId">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-
          ontology-41#Sensor_Information"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string"/>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#NodeName -
           ->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&p0;NodeName">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-
            ontology-41#Sensor_Information"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string"/>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Classes
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->






    <owl:Class rdf:about="&p0;Application_Server"/>




    <owl:Class rdf:about="&p0;Information"/>




    <owl:Class rdf:about="&p0;Management"/>




    <owl:Class rdf:about="&p0;MiddlewareManagement">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&p0;Management"/>
    </owl:Class>





    <owl:Class rdf:about="&p0;ProviderManagement">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&p0;Management"/>
    </owl:Class>





    <owl:Class rdf:about="&p0;SensorManagement">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&p0;Management"/>
    </owl:Class>





    <owl:Class rdf:about="&p0;SensorMiddleware">
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&p0;ConnectsTo"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#SensorServiceProvider"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
    </owl:Class>





    <owl:Class rdf:about="&p0;SensorSupportToolbox"/>





    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#ContentService">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#Services"/>
    </owl:Class>





    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#Device">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&owl;Thing"/>
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&p0;ConnectsTo"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="&p0;SensorMiddleware"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
    </owl:Class>





    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#Middleware_Information">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&p0;Information"/>
    </owl:Class>





    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#Process"/>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#ProviderService -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#ProviderService">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#Services"/>
    </owl:Class>   

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#Sensing">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#Process"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#SensingService -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#SensingService">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#Services"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#Sensing_Device -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#Sensing_Device">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#Device"/>
    </owl:Class>





    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#Sensor">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#Device"/>
    </owl:Class>




    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#SensorServiceProvider">
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&p0;ConnectsTo"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="&p0;Application_Server"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
    </owl:Class>





    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#Sensor_Information">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&p0;Information"/>
    </owl:Class>





    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#Services"/>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Individuals
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#APPServer -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&p0;APPServer">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&p0;Application_Server"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#MW1 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&p0;MW1">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&p0;SensorMiddleware"/>
        <hasInformation rdf:resource="&p0;MiddlewareInfo"/>
        <ConnectsTo rdf:resource="&p0;SSP1"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#MW2 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&p0;MW2">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&p0;SensorMiddleware"/>
        <hasInformation rdf:resource="&p0;MiddlewareInfo"/>
        <ConnectsTo rdf:resource="&p0;SSP1"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#MW3 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&p0;MW3">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&p0;SensorMiddleware"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#Management1 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&p0;Management1">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&p0;Management"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#MiddlewareInfo -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&p0;MiddlewareInfo">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#Middleware_Information"/>
        <MiddlewareCode rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">021</MiddlewareCode>
        <MiddlewareID rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">MW021</MiddlewareID>
        <MiddlewareRight rdf:datatype="&xsd;boolean">false</MiddlewareRight>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#SSP1 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&p0;SSP1">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#SensorServiceProvider"/>
        <ConnectsTo rdf:resource="&p0;APPServer"/>
        <Store rdf:resource="&p0;MiddlewareInfo"/>
        <Store rdf:resource="&p0;SensorInfo"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#SSP2 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&p0;SSP2">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#SensorServiceProvider"/>
        <Store rdf:resource="&p0;MiddlewareInfo"/>
        <Store rdf:resource="&p0;SensorInfo"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#SST1 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&p0;SST1">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&p0;SensorSupportToolbox"/>
        <initiates rdf:resource="&p0;Management1"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#Sensor1 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&p0;Sensor1">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#Sensor"/>
        <ConnectsTo rdf:resource="&p0;MW1"/>
        <hasInformation rdf:resource="&p0;SensorInfo"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#Sensor2 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&p0;Sensor2">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#Sensor"/>
        <ConnectsTo rdf:resource="&p0;MW2"/>
        <hasInformation rdf:resource="&p0;SensorInfo"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#SensorInfo -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&p0;SensorInfo">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#Sensor_Information"/>
        <NodeCode rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">021</NodeCode>
        <NodeId rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">sd021</NodeId>
        <NodeName rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">sensor021</NodeName>
        <NodeExplain rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">temp</NodeExplain>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    </rdf:RDF>
```

The query that I'm running is:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX p0: <http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#>
SELECT ?x
WHERE {?x rdf:type p0:Information}
```

I can provide more details if it is not clear.

Comment: What does "not works" mean?  You mean you get the a non-zero but wrong number of individuals back?  You get no individuals back?  The server crashes?  What happens?  Without seeing your ontology we can't say what any particular query should return.  Without seeing your complete query (the query in your question isn't complete;  it doesn't include prefix declarations), we can't say what might be wrong with it.  Please share your data and the complete query.

Comment: Until those updates are made, -1 since the question isn't clear, and voting to close since "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: The data in your question is not valid OWL: it is missing namespace and entity declaration as well as an an opening and closing element. This makes it impossible to try and duplicate your problem, since the specific namespaces and/or entities declarations in your data may well be part of the issue. Please make sure that your question is Complete, and includes all necessary info to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question. It would have been even better if you had made it a more minimal example, and had also provided some info on what you expected your query to return vs what it actually returned - you leave us to do a lot of guessing. However, I have made an attempt at answering your question, see below.

Answer (score 0):

I loaded your data into a Sesame store and executed a few queries to see what is going on.

The query you are doing tries to retrieve all instances of the class `http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#Information`. However, your data contains no instances of this class, so the result is empty.

We can see this quite easily by running the query:

```
PREFIX p0: <http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#>
DESCRIBE p0:Information
```

which gives us this result:

```
p0:Information rdf:type owl:Class .
p0:Store rdfs:range p0:Information .
<http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#Middleware_Information> rdfs:subClassOf p0:Information .
<http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/7/untitled-ontology-41#Sensor_Information> rdfs:subClassOf p0:Information .
```

As you can see, no triples exist with `rdf:type` as the predicate and `p0:Information` as the object, so no instances are available.

However, there *are* two subclasses of `p0:Information` in your ontology, and they may have instances. Were you expecting to get those back? That will only work if the store you're querying has RDFS reasoning enabled - which most triplestores by default do not enable.

So if you want to get instances of subclasses back, either enable reasoning on your triplestore, or alternatively use the following query:

```
PREFIX p0: <http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/serviceproviderimplementation#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?x 
WHERE {
  ?x rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* p0:Information .
}
```

This uses a property path to retrieve all values `?x` that have class that is related via zero or more `rdfs:subClassOf` relations to `p0:Information`.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your help. God bless you. i got the exact same answer  i wanted through your query. But it still does not work when i try to retreive instances of subclass of Device  class.